# How dose an algorithm access components of a Data structure in STL

Tags: stl, theory

The Standard Template Library (STL) provides data structures and
algorithms. However, it is not the case that every algorithm can be used with every data
structure. Suppose that the STL supports the use of an algorithm A with a data structure D.

(a) How is the link between A and D established. In other words, how does A access
components of D? Give examples.

(b) The STL guarantees (i.e., promises) something about the result of using A with D.
What is the guarantee?

---

A) The STL also provides various "iterators" to access elements on the data structures. There are various types of Iterators, they can travel linearly from the start to the end, some can travel in both directions, and some can move freely to any element in D. The type of iterator supported by D will determine the type of A that can be run using D.

B) If A can be run on D then the STL guarantees the time-complexity (O(n)) that it will take to complete the A.

Hello! i am studying for a theory exam. I was wondering if you all think i missed something in my answers here.

Comment: For (b), you might want to add that an algorithm will never change the structure of a container (i.e. its size and storage).

Answer (score 0):

"(a) How is the link between A and D established. In other words, how does A access components of D? Give examples."

It is done through iterators. Iterators are the glue between algorithms and data structures in STL.
I will use c++11 for my example:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 5, 3, 4};
std::list<int> l{1, 4, 8, 3};

auto foundInVecItem = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 3);
//Note: same algorithm used for different data structure.
auto foundInVecItem = std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), 3);
```

This works because `std::find` makes no assumptions about the data structure that is using for the search. It uses the `ForwardIterator` concept for its implementation. You can take a look at iterator categories [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

`std::find` could be implemented something (simplified since it's just for learning) like this:

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator find(ForwardIterator b, ForwardIterator e,
                    typename ForwardIterator::value_type v) {
    while (b != e) {
      if (*b == v) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    return e;
```

}

The important point here is that the iterator interface is being used to access elements of `std::list` or `std::vector` so the algorithm doesn't care about the data structure as long as they provide `ForwardIterator`s.

"(b) The STL guarantees (i.e., promises) something about the result of using A with D. What is the guarantee?"

Sorry, this is too general, what do you mean by that question? If you mean about the big O notation, namely, asymptotic computational cost, yes.
The standard promises a bounded big O cost for each algorithm given a data structure. It depends on the algorithm and the data structure. For example `std::advance`, which advances an iterator a number of steps, is guaranteed to be `O(1)` for `RandomAccessIterator`s and `O(n)` for the rest of them.

"A) The STL also provides various "iterators" to access elements on the data structures. There are various types of Iterators, they can travel linearly from the start to the end, some can travel in both directions, and some can move freely to any element in D. The type of iterator supported by D will determine the type of A that can be run using D.
"

You can take a look at iterator categories [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

"B) If A can be run on D then the STL guarantees the time-complexity (O(n)) that it will take to complete the A."

Yes, that's right. The specification guarantees the asymptotic computational cost of an operation given a data structure.